# How to create addin for VS2005.?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i want to convert my window application, that i developed in VS2005 using C#, as an Add in for Visual Studio 2005. How can i do it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice quick start tutorial in here : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/LineCounterAddin.aspx

It was enough for me to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx) or [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470230843), but you might find the VS2005 information hidden behind the VS2008 stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create one myself, but i didn't have yet time to process the information required:

- ["How Do I?" Visual Studio extensibility videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsx/bb507746.aspx)
- Article series detailing extending visual studio from the beginning:
  [LearnVSXNow!](http://www.codeplex.com/LearnVSXNow/Wiki/View.aspx?title=LearnVSXNowOld&referringTitle=Home)
- Microsofts's [VSX
  Home on Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx)
- [Building your own Visual Studio Source Code Outliner extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/quanto/archive/2008/01/22/building-your-own-visual-studio-source-code-outliner-extension.aspx) (and Quan's whole blog)

Overall I'd recommend waiting for Visual Studio 2010 (or start working with the [fresh beta 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2009/05/18/visual-studio-2010-beta-1-available-today-to-msdn-subscribers.aspx)), because there will be many changes and many more possibilities on extending Visual Studio. (Think WPF.) The code gallery I linked already contains content regarding to this.

Comment: The VS SDK used in 2005/2008 will only be supported in VS2010 for backwards compatibility. MEF ( http://codeplex.com/MEF ) is the new ways to extend VS going forward - but it is not backwards compatible with pre-2010 versions.